# How to fix my internal local host from hanging up?

Tags: python, flask

So just started using Flask.  Created "Hello World".  When trying to do anything more complicated I get all sorts of error.

Tried restarting shell and re-running application.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
`return "<h1>Hello F'd World!<h1>

def salvador():
    return "Hello, Salvador"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I want to see the sub-link for Salvador.  Instead getting:

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1

/Users/tony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2918: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

Don't know if this is relevant or not but I'm getting this from shell:

```
File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list the process using port 5000:

```
sudo lsof -i:5000
```

Then kill the process:

```
kill [pid]
```

Then this should work:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello, Salvador"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Or you can try the default localhost address `'127.0.0.1'` instead of `'0.0.0.0'` just by typing:

```
app.run()
```

Comment: Ok tried the following: 'from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1>Hello Fucked World!<h1>"

def salvador():
    return "Hello, Salvador"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)'

Comment: Still hanging up... with the following error  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1


/Users/tony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2918: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the task running somewhere still, so you can't start it again.

Comment: Where else is it running?  And how do I kill the other task?  Thanks!

Comment: See fizgi's answer above on how to identify the process id and killing it

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted.  I wanted to add the branch to the main app with a branch of  salvador,                                                                                              def salvador():
     return "Hello, Salvador"

Comment: I think the problem is that I am running my flask and kernel in the same environment?  Not sure if I am being entirely accurate but flask is running in the same root as my code... if that makes sense?